# scanf input issue in this code

Tags: c, loops, io, scanf

I am still a beginner in C. This code takes in input like

```
s 10
w 5
s 20
w 10
```

where s is travel time and w is wait time.

then it calculates total bill basing on traveltime and waittime and the fares which are declared as global variables.

This code is not accepting inputs in while loop properly. Can someone please tell me why is it happening like that. And if anything can be improved in this code is also much appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct bill
{
  int travelTime;
  int waitTime;

  float cost;

};

typedef struct bill BILL;

BILL *bill1;



int BASEFARE = 10; // in Rupees
int TRAVELFARE = 1; //in Rupees
float WAITFARE = 0.1; // in Rupees


int main()
{

    int choice = 1;

    bill1 = (BILL*)malloc(sizeof(BILL));

    bill1->travelTime = 0;
    bill1->waitTime = 0;

    while(choice)
    {
        char state = ' ';
        int period = 0;
        printf("Enter  state\n");
        //scanf("%c %d",&state,&period);
        scanf("%c %d",&state, &period);



        if(state == 's')
        {
            bill1->travelTime = bill1->travelTime + period;
        }
        else if(state == 'w')
        {
            bill1->waitTime = bill1->waitTime + period;
        }
        else if(state == 'e')
        {
            printf("\nTotal TravelTime is %d s ",bill1->travelTime);
            printf("\nTotal WaitTime is %d s", bill1->waitTime);

            bill1->cost = BASEFARE + (bill1->travelTime * TRAVELFARE) + (bill1->waitTime * WAITFARE);

            choice = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nError in data format please ReEnter data\n");
            free(bill1);
            choice = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe Final bill is %f", bill1->cost);

return 0;
}
```

> ```
>  OUTPUT
>     ________________
>     Enter  state
>     s 10
>     Enter  state
>     w 5 
>
>     Error in data format please ReEnter data
>
>     The Final bill is 0.000000
> ```

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged C++? 2. You should not cast `malloc`. 3 `scanf("%c %d",&state, &period);`->`scanf(" %c %d",&state, &period);`

Comment: I thought anyone who can answer C++ related questions can also easily answer this. No ?

Comment: @EdHeal Why not Typecast???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Please choose one language (C or C++). You don't need any pointers or dynamic allocation whatsoever for this program. Also note `malloc.h` is not a standard header.

Comment: Alright i removed C++ from the tags.

Comment: Why don't the program work ??

Comment: Also - read the manual page and note the return value

Comment: What is `malloc.h`?

Comment: which library does malloc come from ?. I'm sorry i'm still new to this

Comment: @VineethSai check my updated answer, `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @gsamaras Yes sir i did, Thank you very much

Comment: Get use to reading the manual pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a space in my scanf statement make a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166197/why-does-a-space-in-my-scanf-statement-make-a-difference)

Comment: @EdHeal Sure , Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%c %d", &state, &period);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %c %d", &state, &period);
```

Whitespace in the format string matches 0 or more whitespace characters in the input.

---

PS: `malloc()` is declared in `stdlib.h`.

"malloc.h" is not a Standard header, so it shouldn't be like `#include<malloc.h>`. If it's a custom header, it should be enclosed with double quotes, like this: `#include "malloc.h"`. If you don't have a custon header named "malloc.h", discard this include.

---

Unrelated to your problem, but [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.

Comment: Wow this worked. Thank you very much.
Is there any reason behind this ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation